# D3 no me muestra datos actualizados

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Estoy haciendo un grafico con d3, tengo dos checkbox, cada cual hace referencia a una serie de datos, lo que quiero es cuando pulse en uno y este activado muestre los datos. Ya hice este metodo para jqplot, pero a la hora de actualizar los datos en jqplot era tan facil como usar `redraw`. Ahora en d3.js no entiendo muy bien como hacerlo. Os dejo el método:

```
function mostrarDatos(){
                nowData=[]
                if($("#eae").prop('checked') == true)
                {
                    nowData.push(eaepunt1[coundata])
                }

                if($("#arab").prop('checked') == true)
                {
                    nowData.push(arabpunt1[coundata])
                }
                console.log(nowData)
                svg.selectAll("circle")
                .data(nowData)
                .attr("cx", function(d) {
                    return xScale(d[0]);
                 })
                .attr("cy", function(d) {
                    return yScale(d[1]);
                 })
            }
```

Por último añadiros algo de informacion, `nowData` es el Array de datos que quiero mostrar. `eaepunt1` es el Array de datos que contiene `x` e `y` del gráfico, este hace referencia al primer checkbox, `arabpunt1` es el Array de datos del segundo checkbox, también contiene `x` e `y` para el gráfico.

Los datos al principio los pinto de esta manera:

```
    var datos = svg.selectAll("circle")
       .data(nowData)
       .enter()
       .append("circle")
       .attr("cx", function(d) {
            return xScale(d[0]);
       })
       .attr("cy", function(d) {
            return yScale(d[1]);
       })
       .attr("r", function(d) {
            return 5;
       })
       ;
```

Creo que he dejado toda la informacion primordial aquí, si tenéis alguna duda en algo comentádmelo y editaré la pregunta.

### EDITADO

He conseguido mostrar los datos cambiando el metodo `mostrarDatos()` de esta manera:

```
    function mostrarDatos(){
        nowData=[]
        if($("#eae").prop('checked') == true)               
        {   
            nowData.push(eaepunt1[coundata])                                    
        }               

        if($("#arab").prop('checked') == true)
        {
            nowData.push(arabpunt1[coundata])                                                               
        }                                           
        console.log(nowData)                            
        svg.selectAll("circle")
           .data(nowData)
           .enter()            
           .append("circle")                           
           .attr("cx", function(d) {
                return xScale(d[0]);
           })
           .attr("cy", function(d) {
                return yScale(d[1]);
           })
           .attr("r", function(d) {
                return 5;
           })              
           ;
    }
```

Pero cuando desmarco el check se siguen mostrando los datos

Answer (score 0):

Al final he conseguido hacerlo. Habia que añadir un exit y un remove al principio del metodo. No entiendo muy bien porque pero funciona:

```
function mostrarDatos(){
                nowData=[]
                svg.selectAll("circle")
                    .data(nowData)
                    .exit()
                    .remove()
                if($("#eae").prop('checked') == true)               
                {   
                    nowData.push(eaepunt1[coundata])                                    
                    svg.selectAll("circle")

                }               

                if($("#arab").prop('checked') == true)
                {
                    nowData.push(arabpunt1[coundata])                                                               

                }                                           
                console.log(nowData)

                svg.selectAll("circle")
                   .data(nowData)
                   .enter()            
                   .append("circle")                           
                   .attr("cx", function(d) {
                        return xScale(d[0]);
                   })
                   .attr("cy", function(d) {
                        return yScale(d[1]);
                   })
                   .attr("r", function(d) {
                        return 5;
                   })              
                   ;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola gracias por tus comentarios, oye si has trabajado con JqPlot, Sabras por que cuando la gráfica la convierto a imagen se distorciona un poco, se ve más grande y no sale completa, ojala me pudieras ayudar, muchas gracias

Saludos

Comment: Esto no constituye una solución al problema, por lo que no debes ponerlo como respuesta, es más bien un comentario. Sigue participando por acá y pronto llegarás a obtener suficientes puntos de reputación para poder publicar comentarios. Saludos!